# javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class ** nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I have a generic web service which is expecting a `WebServiceRequest` object. This object has a payload which is of type Object. Below is the type of my payload.

```
<xs:complexType name="payload">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="lax"></xs:any>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I created `JAXB` classes for the web service input and output types. So for payload, this the field that was generated.

```
 @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
 private Object any;
```

Below is the structure of my `JAXB` generated `WebServiceRequest` VO.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "serviceRequest", namespace = "http://ws.test.svc.com/", propOrder = {
    "payload"
})
public class WebServiceRequest{
        @XmlElement
        private Payload payload;
} 

public class Payload{
 @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
 private Object any;
}
```

I have some custom POJOs which I need to populate and set as the payload. I annotated these POJOs using the following annotation

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AddressVO {
    @XmlElement
    private String pinCode;
    @XmlElement
    private String city;
}
```

I populated the data for this POJO and tried to set as the payload of `WebServiceRequest`. But when I do that, I'm getting the below exception.

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.vo.test.AddressVO nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

Could you please suggest some ways to overcome this? In one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057932/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-class-nor-any-of-its-super-class-is-known-to-t) it was mentioned to include `@XmlSeeAlso`, but i can't do that since my payload is very generic. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Could you also include the snippet of your JAXBContext instantiation?

Comment: It is not done by me actually. I think WebSphere is doing it internally.

Comment: please put the stack trace with line numbers visible

Comment: Have u tried using the method - JAXBContext newInstance(String contextPath,ClassLoader classLoader)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case that you can't apply the `@XMLSeeAlso` annotation, you will need to create a custom `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` which are responsible to marshall and unmarshall between java and XML. Below there is shown an abstract implementation of a generic `MessageBodyReader` which was actually intended to perfom a type specific XML validation. The writer is quite similar, hence it isn't added.

```
public abstract class AbstractXmlValidationReader<T> implements
        MessageBodyReader<T> {

    private final Providers providers;
    private final Schema schema;

    public AbstractXmlValidationReader(final Providers providers,
            final ServletContext servletContext, final String xsdFileName) {
        this.providers = providers;

        try {
            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory
                    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            File xsd = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(xsdFileName));
            schema = sf.newSchema(xsd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to create XSD validation schema", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<T> readableClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        if (type == readableClass
                && type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
            ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = providers
                    .getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);
            if (null != resolver) {
                jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type);
            }
            if (null == jaxbContext) {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            }
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T entity = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(entityStream);
            return entity;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new MessageBodyReaderValidationException(
                    "Failure while performing xml validation or xml marhalling!",
                    e);
        }
    }
}
```

And a concreate implementation for type `Address`

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class AddressXmlValidationReader extends
        AbstractXmlValidationReader<Address> {

    private final static String xsdFileName = "/xsd/Address.xsd";

    public AddressXmlValidationReader(@Context Providers providers,
            @Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        super(providers, servletContext, xsdFileName);
    }
}
```

What you need now is a slighlty modified `readFrom` method of the `MessageBodyReader` which may look as followed. For the `MessageBodyWriter` the method is called `writeTo`.

```
@Override
public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = providers
                .getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);

        if(entityStream != null){
            // TODO read the entityStream and determine the concrete type of the XML content
            type = ... ;
        }

        if (null != resolver) {
            jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type);
        }
        if (null == jaxbContext) {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
        }
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T entity = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(entityStream);
        return entity;
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new MessageBodyReaderValidationException(
                "Failure while performing xml validation or xml marhalling!",
                e);
    }
}
```

With this approach you define a general type via the concrete subclass of the Reader and Writer instance. And a possible more specific type can either be determine within the abstract base class (like in this example) or it's getted injected from somewhere else. Of course you can modify this `MessageBodyReader` so that the concrete type fo the XML input is determined somewhere or somehow else. But in general this is the way how you will solve your issue.

---

***Notice:***

Don't forget to register the concrete Reader and writer implementation in the web services `Application` class.

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class WSApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    public WSApplication() {
        ...
        classes.add(AddressXmlValidationReader.class);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```