# Gradle: created jar by gradle bootJar task is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, soap

Created jar by gradle task bootJar is not working. Get javax.xml.bind.JAXBException. But everything works fine using gradle bootRun or through IDEA

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.xxx.PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:593) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar!/:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:482) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar!/:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar!/:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar!/:2.2.6]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$1.run(JAXBDSContext.java:477) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$1.run(JAXBDSContext.java:462) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshalByElement(JAXBDSContext.java:462) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshal(JAXBDSContext.java:422) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._outputFromBO(JAXBBlockImpl.java:175) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.outputTo(BlockImpl.java:371) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.serialize(BlockImpl.java:295) ~[axis2-jaxws-1.7.9.jar!/:1.7.9]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.serializer.push.stax.StAXSerializer.serializePushOMDataSource(StAXSerializer.java:53) ~[axiom-dom-1.2.21.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.serializer.push.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:293) ~[axiom-dom-1.2.21.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest what is the code for this class

Comment: @ApiModel(value = "PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest")
public class PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest {
}

Answer (score 0):

```
@ApiModel(value = "PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest", description = "Запрос на получение сводки по количеству ПП на подпись и отправку")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @XmlType(name = "") 
@XmlRootElement(name = "PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest")
@XmlSeeAlso({PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest.class}) //add this and try
public class PayOrderStatisticsGetRequest { }
```

reference [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Class *** nor any of its super class is known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057932/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-class-nor-any-of-its-super-class-is-known-to-t)

Comment: Using bootRun I see this model in JAXBContext, but using bootJar don't