# How to use an explicitly specified marshaller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jaxb

I'm trying to create a REST service that is able to produce XML output (I have a custom class that is wrapped inside a HATEOAS object). Mapping is like this:

```
@GetMapping("/customclass")
Resource<CustomClass> custom() {
    return new Resource<CustomClass>(new CustomClass());
}

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not marshal [Resource { content: CustomClass(a=10, string=abc), links: [] }]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class test.CustomClass nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class test.CustomClass nor any of its super class is known to this context.]]
```

I'm pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with my CustomClass. If I use the following mapping instead

```
@GetMapping("/customclass")
CustomClass custom() {
    return (new CustomClass());
}
```

then it works fine.

It also works fine if I try to marshal things manually (by settings things up inside of a main method and then running it). It's also fine then if I wrap the instance of CustomClass inside of a Resource instance.

As far I understand the issue is that the marshaller in SpringApplication is using context that just knows about HATEOAS Resource and I need to some how make it aware of CustomClass.

I tried to use something like this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40398632)

```
@Configuration
public class ResponseResolver  {
    @Bean
    public Marshaller marshaller() {
        try {
            System.out.println("getting marshaller");
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomClass.class, Resource.class);
            return context.createMarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but that didn't work (there was a lot of guessing on my part here, since I don't know that much about the inner workings of Spring Boot).

A promising reply was also in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073899 , but ContextResolver wasn't in my projects classpath.

I also considered wrapping Resource inside of a another class and then using XmlSeeAlso annotation, but that would mess up my XML and would be somewhat ugly hack.

So is it possible to define a custom JAXBContext that SpringApplication would be able to pick up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spring Boot Documentation 
[Spring Message message converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-pathmatch)

> Spring MVC uses the HttpMessageConverter interface to convert HTTP
>   requests and responses. Sensible defaults are included out of the box.
>   For example, objects can be automatically converted to JSON (by using
>   the Jackson library) or XML (by using the Jackson XML extension, if
>   available, or by using JAXB if the Jackson XML extension is not
>   available). By default, Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter –
>   converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on
>   the classpath)

**Custom Converters Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        messageConverters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = 
          new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

        return xmlConverter;
    }
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right way and I managed to get it to work. The code you gave has couple of issues. For some reason `new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()` doesn't have any effect on `Accept:application/xml` requests. You're solution does however work when making `createXmlHttpMessageConverter` `public` and adding `@Bean` annotation to it (Spring boot picks it up automatically then). Thank you! Any idea why adding the converter is implemented with those two additions to a list (can't understand at all why it's like this)?