# How to convert eclipse dynamic web app into executable jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hi can anyone please tell me how to convert the eclipse dynamic web app into executable jar. I need to use this jar in another application to generate the jsps. So even after adding into another project it should be working as web app only.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why it needs to be a jar? Why you need it be executable if you want to use in another application? What kind of resources you need to generate jsps?

Comment: HI @Garry Thanks for reply. Actually I have web application which generates the template jsp based on the user input with responsive UI. So I need to convert it as jar for using in the other web applications. Can you please help me for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Dynamic web projects you cannot create an  Executable jar file,but you always have an option to export as .War file that you can include to build and EAR file which can include multiple .war files from other Dynamic web applications as well. How this war can communicate with other war files with  in EAR for that you can refer this [Options to communicate between WARs in the same EAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359548/options-to-communicate-between-wars-in-the-same-ear)

Comment: Is der any way to make my web app to use as jar or war to use in another application to generate the jsp template based on the user input values.

Comment: your other application is also an web application ?

Comment: Yes. My another application is spring MVC app.

Comment: i don't think so you can.. but you have other options too.. to utilize the functionality of one application from other.. best example i would say as web service. or include both application into same EAR and make them communicate with each other